# How to Insert data into embedded Map in Orient DB?

Tags: orientdb

I have Class Name Contacts and it has following properties.

name, type string
phone, type embeddedMap , link type string..

I want insert data using a query..
Please assit me to do this.
Thank You.

Comment: Please provide more details here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: insert into Contacts name="bonie",phone={"home":"55555555","mobile":"8888888"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create vertex Contacts set name="pippo",phone={"home":"55555555","mobile":"8888888"},link="http://qwertyuiop"
```

Comment: Can't we insert data like this?

`insert into Contacts name="bonie",phone={"home":"55555555","mobile":"8888888"}`

Comment: yes you can, but with a small correction: you need the SET word `insert into Contacts set name="bonie",phone={"home":"55555555","mobile":"8888888"}`

Comment: Thank you very much... After inserting how can i retrieve them?

Comment: well, it depends on what you need, here are some examples: `select phone.mobile from Contacts` , `select phone.home,link from Contacts where name="pippo"` , `select from Contacts`